# PHP- How to read files from FTP in PHP?

Tags: php, html, ftp

I have 2 files. One is email.php and link.html. I have used anchor tag

**< a href="email.php?file=ftp://ftp.firstnorthglobal.com/report_ledger.html">Click< /a>**

in link.html and want to read report_ledger.html which is located on FTP server. I can connect with FTP server but I am getting following error :

**Connected as ftpkalpesh@ftp.firstnorthglobal.com 
Warning: file_get_contents(ftp.firstnorthglobal.com/report_ledger.html) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

and

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_IoException' with message 'Unable to open file for reading [ftp.firstnorthglobal.com/shreelogo.png]' in C:\xampp\Swift-5.0.3\lib\classes\Swift\ByteStream\FileByteStream.php:139 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\Swift-5.0.3\lib\classes\Swift\ByteStream\FileByteStream.php(86): Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream->_getReadHandle() #1 C:\xampp\Swift-5.0.3\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\ContentEncoder\Base64ContentEncoder.php(36): Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream->read(8190) #2 C:\xampp\Swift-5.0.3\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\SimpleMimeEntity.php(557): Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder_Base64ContentEncoder->encodeByteStream(Object(Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream), Object(Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer), 0, 78) #3 C:\xampp\Swift-5.0.3\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\SimpleMimeEntity.php(532): Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity->_bodyToByteStream(Object(Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer)) #4 C:\xampp\Swift-5.0.3\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\SimpleMimeEntity.php(572): Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity->toByteStream(Object(Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer)) #5 C:\x in C:\xampp\Swift-5.0.3\lib\classes\Swift\ByteStream\FileByteStream.php on line 139

I did not use any file reading function. What would you suggest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you use this function as you want to open a local file and not a remote one.

Look at docs here: [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents)

When i talk about URL and try to enable:   [fopen wrappers](https://www.php.net/manual/it/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)

Personal idea( this example is to upload but if you use ftp_get instead of ftp_put you can find the solution ):

```
<?php

// define some variables
$local_file = 'local.zip';
$server_file = 'server.zip';

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
   echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
   echo "There was a problem\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

Comment: can you explain a but further ?

Comment: file_get_contents(<file>)
file must be a file that is present in the local site/machine.
With fopen you can use an url of remote...
But i think that the best solutions is to open a ftp tunnel in php and here read the file localy to the machine.

like explained here: http://www.php.net/manual/it/book.ftp.php

Comment: Yeap...So now how to use fopen wrappers instead of file_get_contents. Any example for clear idea?

Comment: Getting error : Warning: ftp_get() [function.ftp-get]: Error opening in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\email report\email.php on line 18
There was a problem while reading ftp://ftp.firstnorthglobal.com/report_ledger.html

Comment: I can successfully attach file from FTP server, but I want to read the file's contents and want t send it via email. I want to extract HTML contents. getting this error : Warning: file_get_contents(ftp://ftp.firstnorthglobal.com/report_ledger.html) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: operation failed in

Comment: I edit the code sample, try with this and if the problem persist we can find a way to receive a more specific error detail.

Comment: Yes.This can be one way. refer Above comment,you will get the idea what i want.

Comment: No problem, when you have a local file getted from ftp that contains the html that you want to send use this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
In particular case of html content:
http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=416467